# How can I resolve authentication error in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, .net-core

I'm creating a angular application and I have an error when I want to authenticate someone even if it's the login is right.

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText:
>   "OK", url: "http://localhost:50518/api/Employee", ok: false, …} error:
>   error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0 at
>   JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad
>   (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:7076:51) at
>   ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2743:31) at Object.onInvokeTask
>   (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:34894:33) at
>   ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2742:36) at
>   Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask
>   (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2510:47) at
>   ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask
>   [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2818:34) at invokeTask
>   (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3862:14) at
>   XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback
>   (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3888:17) text:
>   "test-test"
>   **proto**: Object headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ} message: "Http failure during parsing
>   for http://localhost:50518/api/Employee" name: "HttpErrorResponse" ok:
>   false status: 200 statusText: "OK" url:
>   "http://localhost:50518/api/Employee"
>   **proto**: HttpResponseBase

My authentication service :

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  header = new HttpHeaders({
    "content-type" : "application/JSON"
  })

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private config : ApiConfigService,
    private router : Router) { }


login(username: string, password: string): Observable<HttpResponse<Authentication>>{
  return this.http.post<Authentication>(`http://localhost:50518/api/Employee`, {
    username: username,
    password: password
  }, {
    headers : this.header,
    observe : "body",
    responseType : "text"
  });
}
}
```

I didn't understand why I have this error I don't think it comes from my .Net Core API.

Update the problem comes from my .Net Core API I do a : `return Ok()` but when I switch with a `return Json()` it works.

Comment: The `SyntaxError` means the response from the server is invalid JSON and cannot be parsed.

Comment: I update my code but always an error

Answer (score 1):

Is the response you are getting back a valid json? Can you post what you are getting back from the API? It looks like it's trying to parse JSON, but it's getting something else, maybe a string? If this is the case you need to specify responseType to the HTTP service. If it's a string you need to specify you are expecting back a 'text'.

This is the overload method from Angulars HTTP service that you should be using: (assuming you are getting back a string):

```
  /**
 * Construct a POST request which interprets the body as text and returns it.
 *
 * @return an `Observable` of the body as a `string`.
 */
post(url: string, body: any | null, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType: 'text';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<string>;
```

You post should look something like this:

```
 login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:50518/api/Employee`, {
    username: username,
    password: password
  }, {
    headers : this.header,
    observe : "body",
    responseType : "text"
  });
}
```

From what I understand, there are 2 problems here: 1st is that you client code expects a JSON because you are using a generic param in the post call but you are returning a string from the API. If you choose to return a string from the API you need to remove the generic parameter from http.post

And in you API code, return Ok('your string here')

Comment: Try using  responseType : "text" instead of  responseType : "json"

Comment: If i do that I have an error in my IDE -> Property type 'observe' are incompatiible.
    Can't assign '"response"' to '"body"'

Comment: observe needs to be set to body and not response. observe : "body".

Comment: Ok I try but I have an error again and I update my code

Comment: Ty for your help so I have error for the post it say : overload is incompatiible with the implementation of  the fonction and the property types 'responseType' are incompatible. Can't assign type text to json.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: I use the last one

Comment: Can you please post the full error you are getting now?

Comment: My IDE error ? or if my browser error when I delete the change it is the same.

Comment: Hum I'm so sorry for taking your time ... my problem comes from my api when I do my return in .Net Core I use return ok() instead of return json()

Comment: ok() should return valid JSON. what are you passing as a parameter? an object or a primitive? Your IDE is showing that error because of the generic param. But by the sounds of it, you are returning an object, therefore setting responseType to text will not help.

Comment: Ok my return ok param are : 
Return OK(username + "-"+"password")

Comment: I have a question how can I don't have a post error bad request when the authentication is false ?

Comment: how does your Authentication object look in Angular?

Comment: I try your code but it return me the same error for responsetype

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are passing proper content-type headers as application/JSON.

Comment: I try to put a content-type headers as application/JSON but it doesn't work I update my question